# filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for LinqBridge.dll in

Tags: php, function, filesize, stat

i write a script to list my file from Update directory with this option:

file-name file-hash file-size

why i get this error:

```
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for LinqBridge.dll in      C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php on line 15
```

my php cod:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['action']) and ($_GET['action']=="list"))
 {
    $myDirectory = opendir("./Update/");
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
$dirArray[] = $entryName;
 }
    closedir($myDirectory);
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);
    sort($dirArray);
   for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
    if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){
    echo $dirArray[$index]."&nbsp;";
    echo @hash_file('md5',$dirArray[$index])."&nbsp;";
    echo filesize($dirArray[$index])."&nbsp;";
}
 }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Does the user ID this script is running under have access rights to that file, and are you using the correct path to get at that file?

Comment: yes and yes i am using the correct path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files in $dirArray are located in a different directory. You are reading them from "./Update/" thus when doing a filesize or filectime or filemtime or wahtever else, you need to prefix with "./Update/".

```
echo filesize("./Update/".$dirArray[$index])."&nbsp;";
```

Comment: thank you worked.  and other question: may file name in my host is  Launcher[dot]exe but i want in echo its showed in real name like that:Launcher.exe can id do?

Comment: I didn't understand your message, please rephrase it and check your english, it's unreadable right now...

Comment: i have some file in multiple format like as .exe & .dll & .txt but for some reason i changed the format .exe to [dot]exe and in this script result(echo) the [dot]exe not showed as .exe i want it showed like .exe not [dot]exe.

Comment: i did that:    **        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){
  $text = explode('[dot]',$dirArray[$index]);
  echo $text[0];
  if(@$text[1]!="") echo ".".$text[1];
        echo @hash_file('md5',$dirArray[$index])."&nbsp;";
  echo filesize("./Update/".$dirArray[$index])."&nbsp;";  **     but now the file hash not showed?!!

Comment: echo str_replace('[dot]', '.', $dirArray[$index])

Comment: i used your code: str_replace('[dot]', '.', $dirArray[$index]) and its worked but the file hash not showed?!

Comment: Look, our job is not to code for you, you need tounderstand what you want to achieve and understand what you are doing or else you'll never make it out. Try to understand your code, clean it up, test up stuff and move on.